# Response.Redirect using HTTPS and IE edge causing error outputs content of header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, response.redirect

I am experiencing a lot of troubles with the new browser Edge in Windows 10. I am getting problems when I try to response.redirect a user after login to a default page.

The problem is that it outputs the content of the header to the page instead of redirecting me to the correct page. (see attached image) and if I refresh the page I get redirected correctly and the page shows up as it should.

The problem only appears when I try to use HTTPS along with my application and it only appears in Edge, all other browsers even previous versions of internet explorer works perfectly.

The code I use to response.redirect user is and to be sure iv'e added the https manually before I used Response.Redirect('~\Default.aspx)' which also works but just to be sure I added the https prefix manually using the below code.

```
Dim url As String = String.Format("https://{0}{1}", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), "/Default.aspx")
Response.Redirect(url)
```

I've stepped through the code and the content of the url looks like
https://localhost:44300/Default.aspx so it should work and it looks exactly like it does in every other browser where it works.

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtKuD.jpg)

Any known issues with Edge? I've also tried forcing compatbitlity mode IE9 / IE8 which doesnt seem to work in Edge with no luck, so I am running out of options.

The only way I can get this to work is to stop using https and force the use of http.

Any advice on what I can try next or perhaps do to fix this?

Best regards Marcus

Comment: I have a doubt: the default port to HTTPS is 443 and not 44300. Shouldn´t it causing the problem? I guess also the port is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there also any URL REDIRECTOR functioning in the website?

Comment: @DavidBS What do you mean with URL redirector? I have this in my global.asax. 
Sub Application_BeginRequest
       
            If (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False)) Then
            Response.Redirect("https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
        End If
    End Sub

But this shouldnt matter as far as I am aware, because I believe somehow this is the fact why it is working when I am refreshing the webpage since then its the only time its getting triggered and reroutes me to the correct page?

Comment: No, this code you appended is just a normal code to provide HTTPS prefix to all secure connections; and I was talking about an URL REDIRECTOR plugin in IIS to provide more complex redirection, which could create 301 erros in some scenarios. Anyway, did you tried to change port to 443?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that sadly it didnt work, same error is given, really weird

Comment: Try to use the port only ("http://xxxxx:443") OR the prefix only ("https://xxxx").

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Sadly not, havent been able to figure it out yet. I think it has something to do when having response redirecting from http to https or vice versa. 

But I am started to get a bit clue less. If you happen to solve it, please let me know.